# SQL query with optional parameters with python

Tags: python, postgresql, arguments

whene I execute my script python with arguments a, b, c;

```
var1 = sys.arg[1]
var2 = sys.arg[2]
var3 = sys.arg[3]

cursor.execute("select * from table where  a= %s, b= %s, c= %s ", (var1, var2, var3))
```

but I also want these parameters to be optional, I mean insert just one or two parameter for example.
if I enter two parameters, my query takes into account only two parameters (a and c).

how can I do that please, thank for your help

Comment: How will you be passing in the variable column names?

Comment: when I execute my script like : python var1 var3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the argparse module to ensure "var1" lines up with column "a" while "var3" relates to column "c".

```py
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

# provide a clear definition of possible arguments
parser.add_argument('--a', type=str, required=False, default=None)
parser.add_argument('--b', type=str, required=False, default=None)
parser.add_argument('--c', type=str, required=False, default=None)

# get arguments passed in
args = parser.parse_args()

args = args.__dict__

# form statement based on arguments that were given
columns = ', '.join([x+'=%s' for x in args if args[x]])     #check that args[x] is not None

vars = tuple([args[x] for x in args if args[x]])

statement = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE "+columns

cursor.execute(statement, vars)
```

That would form the statement:

```py
'SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE a=%s, c=%s'
```

You would call your script like this:

```py
script.py --a=var1 --c=var3
```

Comment: but if for example I have argument 'day' and I have close between like  : 'SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE a between %s and  %s'